# How to replace two different lines of text?

Tags: python, file, replace, txt

I need to create a file that changes the date and name of a .txt, but I can only change one or the other with this code I found on the internet, can anyone give me any tips?

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPcF7.png)

```
import os
from ast import Str

file = open("example.txt", "r")
replacement = ""

data = "02/07/2022"
name = "Alan"


for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    changes = line.replace("__/__/____", data)
    replacement = replacement + changes + "\n"

file.close()

fout = open("final.txt", "w")
fout.write(replacement)
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this a line a time.  You can replace that entire program with this:

```
data = "02/07/2022"
name = "Alan"

text = open("example.txt", "r").read().replace("__/__/____", data)
open("final.txt", "w").write(text)
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks for helping me <3